# RoR reverse proxy (oauth)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, oauth, reverse-proxy

We currently have the following architecture (for a RoR based production system)
  A gateway, which also acts as auth (oauth functionality implemented using DoorKeeper) is the starting point for all requests coming from the front end.

The system is working perfectly well. The task we are faced with now involves addition of a legacy application (written in multiple languages, including ASP.NET). This legacy application currently works fine as a standalone system. What we intend to do is

- Integrate the legacy system within our working system (within our own subnet)
- Do minimum (or if possible zero) modifications to the legacy system
- keep using our oauth layer (gateway) as the first point of contact for all incoming requests (including the requests to the legacy system)

*We are in control of the front end requests and routing, so CSRF is not a concern*

One solution that we are considering is that the auth layer (gateway) also acts as a reverse proxy. In essence any request coming for the legacy environment (from the legacy front end clients) will be authenticated by doorkeeper but they will now be redirected to the legacy server-application and the response is then send back to the client.

The above sounds like a nginx reverse proxy, but I want a RoR gem which I can use because I want this to be flexible for future modifications. For example (but not limited to)

- I can modify the legacy client to start using multiple auth mechanisms (so the request from client to auth layer will have different headers, but I would like to change this request to its legacy format during the journey from auth-legacy-backend-server-application and back) [*easier*]
- I would like to add encryption (SSL) on client to auth (gateway) requests. The gateway will decrypt the request and send un-encrypted request for the auth-legacy-backend-server-application and back journey) [*tougher*]
- A few of the legacy system requests are such that Legacy-FrontEnd (**LFE**) --> Legacy-Backend (**LBE**) use cookie based sessions. I want to use the gateway to simulate this behavior.

  - LFE -> gateway uses my auth mechanism (say encrypted tokens)
  - gateway -> LBE simulates the cookie based sessions behavior
  - gateway keeps the mapping of token to session-cookie

[*the last point above is a over simplification of a use case we might encounter at a later date*]